# Construction of a maximal atlas.

Tags: differential-geometry

Given an smooth atlas on a topological manifold is there a constructive way to define a maximal atlas? Quite obviously all restrictions and all unions of compatible charts will be at maximal atlas, but repeating those operations would we get the entire maximal atlas?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a constructive definition of such an atlas in any meaningful sense. Consider the real line; it is covered by a single chart. On the other hand, a maximal atlas on $R$ contains (but is not restricted to) all diffeomorphisms $R\to R$. How can one possibly "construct" all these?

Comment: I guess I might have been not specific enough. Given smooth atlas, its maximal atlas would contain all charts composed with diffeomorphisms and all restrictions and gluings of existing charts. Would doing those operations inductively give you entire maximal atlas, or there would be something left?